# Why array in $scope doesn't updated using array concat method?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

When I use concat method, my $scope is not updated

```
var anotherList = ["2", "3", "4"];
$scope.list     = [];

$scope.list.concat(anotherList);
```

But using array push method in a loop, my $scope gets updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong.  You need to assign the return value of `.concat()` to your scoped array.

```
$scope.list = $scope.list.concat(anotherList);
```

Alternatively, if you used `call()` you could bind the result directly to the scoped array without the need to "reassign" since it would be done under the hood for you.

```
$scope.list.concat.call(anotherList);
```

See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

Comment: Thank you David L, I'm noob with JavaScript and AngularJS

Comment: @EricdosReis Not a problem!  It's an easy thing to overlook if you don't know what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

What David said is correct. Just to add: concat() doesn't modify the array, it just return a new array based on the parameters received. Check this for more info:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the original array, instead of `concat` you can do:

```
Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.list, anotherList);
```